# How to get Sqlmap to detect insertion point with sleep payload?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a server which seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection with the following payload detected by BurpSuite:

```
param=value,(select*from(select(sleep(10)))a)
```

The application takes twice the time defined in sleep to respond (sleep 10 returns a response after 20 seconds). I am trying to get Sqlmap to detect the insertion point, however it won't pick it up. I have tried with --prefix and --suffix, increasing the risk...

Does anyone know Sqlmap can be tweaked to detect this?

Comment: Did you try `--time-sec=10`?

Comment: I tried --time-sec=45 which didn't work

Comment: Are you sending the payload through `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: It is a POST request

Comment: Looks like your syntax is wrong as you appear to be using the `GET` syntax. The `POST` syntax is something like `sqlmap --data "email=xyz&password=xyz&submit=xyz" -u http://domain.local --risk 3 --level 5`.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES I think OP is already aware about that.

Comment: The syntax I am using for sqlmap is ./sqlmap.py -r burprequest -p "object_id" --prefix="," --dbms=mysql --level=5 --risk=3 --time-sec=10 -v.
The burp request file was saved via the save item option from repeater

Answer (score 2):

Burp Suite won't always pick up right detection. On your question, you noted the application *seemed to be vulnerable*; This meant it's never determined if it's a positive detection. You will need to check if the detection is *Certain* or it's just *Tentative*? (What does Burp Suite tell you?) If it's *Tentative* detection, you could try using SQLMap or rather try detecting manually.

> The application takes twice the time defined in sleep to respond (sleep 10 returns a response after 20 seconds)

Did you try that manually, if yes - there is a probability of a web application firewall.

Since, **SQLMap** is the approach which you've taken - I assume you should be targeting on a particular parameter using `-p` switch and then the name of the parameter which you are testing. You have noted that `--risk` & `--level` doesn't help. It's because if the parameter detection is *Tentative*, it's a false positive.

On a sidenote, use `--tamper=ptm` & `tamper=charencode`, let us know how that went.

Another way could be using `--identify-waf` switch to determine if the target is beyond a firewall which might be dropping interesting packets.