# Sqlmap won't pick up injection point. Tweak?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I manually found an injection point, on CTF VM, located on POST form. I found it with the following manual payload :

```
1' OR SLEEP(1)-- t
```

I would like to use `sqlmap`. I ended with following call :

```
sqlmap -u "http://shop.home/shop/administrator/" --data "username=1&password=2" --level=5 --risk=3 --dbms mysql --technique T -vvv  -p "username,password"
```

- Specify `data` to ensure POST is used, with try to inject on username and password params.
- Rise up `level` and `risk` to extend perimeter
- Focus on MySQL dbms as I'm pretty sure it is (I tried without)
- Focus on time-based techniques as I found one

Among all tries, I saw this one :

```
[PAYLOAD] 2' OR SLEEP(5)-- daCv
```

It's exactly the one showing injection, and if I try using Burp I get the timed response evidence.

Nonetheless, `sqlmap` does not pick it up and it ends showing nothing found.
I'm aware of similar questions (such as [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158277/how-to-get-sqlmap-to-detect-insertion-point-with-sleep-payload)) but in my case, I know for sure it is time based injection. I also tried with `tamper` `charencode`.

I think I got the heuristic `sqlmap` approach overview : I will try with given value in order to get "valid" request, then build according to this metrics the vulnerable response profile.

How can I tweak `sqlmap` to find and exploit this particular injection point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the request via burp then you can use sqlmap with the `-r` flag to load it or you can try `-- forms` flag –